# How to add element in Python to the end of list using list.insert?

Tags: python, list, insert

There is a list, for example,

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
```

I can use

```
a.append(some_value)
```

to add element at the end of list, and

```
a.insert(exact_position, some_value)
```

to insert element on any other position in list **but not at the end** as

```
a.insert(-1, 5)
```

will return [1,2,3,**5**,4].
So how to add an element to the end of list using **list.insert(position, value)**?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You'll have to pass the new ordinal position to `insert` using `len` in this case:

```
In [62]:

a=[1,2,3,4]
a.insert(len(a),5)
a
Out[62]:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 9):

list.insert with any index >= len(of_the_list) places the value at the end of list. It behaves like append

```
Python 3.7.4
>>>lst=[10,20,30]
>>>lst.insert(len(lst), 101)
>>>lst
[10, 20, 30, 101]
>>>lst.insert(len(lst)+50, 202)
>>>lst
[10, 20, 30, 101, 202]
```

Time complexity, append O(1), insert O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try this:

`[1,2,3,4] + [5]`