# Trying to add a new last element in a list while using the method insert()

Tags: python, python-3.x

thanks for reading.

I'm currently learning python, yet a silly question popped in my head.

I was writting some lines of code usinng the things I've learnt and I noticed something that doesn't make "sense" (whatever that means) to me.

Here is my code:

```
//printing the last element of my list

numbers = [5, 4 ,3 ,2 ,1]

print(numbers[-1]) 

//changing values in my list

numbers[0] = 1

numbers[-1] = 1



//inserting values on my list

print(numbers)

numbers.insert(0,"Hello")

**numbers.insert(-1, "Hello")**

print(numbers)
```

the question pops with the line I marked as ****BOLD****: Why I can't modify the last element of my list when I put -1?, I touhght that when you call the element [-1] in a list it shows the last element, why this doesn't work when I'm using the insert () method and calling -1?

this is what happens when you run all the code.

```
1

[1, 4, 3, 2, 1]

['Hello', 1, 4, 3, 2, 'Hello', 1]
```

Comment: See: [How to add element in Python to the end of list using list.insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212447/)

Comment: I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `insert`, you are inserting at the specified index position. Remember that `lst[-x]` is the same as `lst[len(lst)-1-x]`. For example, `lst[-1]` and `lst[len(lst)-1-1]` both refer to the last index position in the list. Once you know this, the behavior you are seeing with the negative index positions starts to make more sense:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

nums.insert(1, 'Hello')  # Insert at index position 1.
# Result: [1, 'Hello', 2, 3, 4, 5]

nums.insert(-1, 'Bye')  # Insert at index position len(nums)-1-1 = 4.
# Same as: nums.insert(4, 'Bye')
# Result: [1, 'Hello', 2, 3, 4, 'Bye', 5]

nums.insert(-2, 'Good')  # Insert at index position len(nums)-1-2 = 5.
# Same as: nums.insert(5, 'Good')
# Result: [1, 'Hello', 2, 3, 4, 'Good', 'Bye', 5]
```

To insert at the end of the list using `insert`:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
nums.insert(len(nums), 'Hello')
# Result: [1, 2, 3, 'Hello']
```

As you can see, `'Hello'` was inserted in index position `3` (the original `len(nums)`) as specified.

If all you want to do is add an element at the end of a list, you could use `append` instead:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
nums.append('Hello')
# Result: [1, 2, 3, 'Hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert at the end of a list, you have to use

```
numbers.insert(len(numbers), 'Hello')
```

This will output

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 'Hello']
```

The problem you faced occurs because `numbers[-i]` is equivalent to `numbers[len(numbers) - 1 - i]`. So, `numbers[-1]` is actually `numbers[5 - 1 - 1]`, i.e., `numbers[3]`, which is exactly what was happening in your program. Insertion was happening at the 3rd index.

Answer (score 0):

> Why I can't modify the last element of my list when I put -1?, I touhght that when you call the element [-1] in a list it shows the last element, why this doesn't work when I'm using the insert () method and calling -1?

Because -1 is `len(x)-1`, it's the position of the last item but it "points to" *right before* the last item<sup>0</sup>, in the same way 0 points *right before* the first item. Basically:

```
 [a][b][c][d][e]
 0  1  2  3  4  5
-5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

Thus in the same way `insert(0, ...)` inserts before the first item, `insert(-1, ...)` inserts right before the last item.

To add an element at the end, you need to insert right *after* the last item.

[0] that's the "pointer" view of indexing, shared by most 0-indexed languages: the index is seen as an offset from the array pointer.