# Some confusion about swapping two elements in a list using a function

Tags: python, function, swap

Simple assignment is to swap first and last values in a list.  However, when I do it, the list doesn't come out as expected.

Here is my code:

```
def swap(values):
    val1 = values_list.pop(0)
    val2 = values_list.pop(-1)

    values_list.insert(-1, val1)
    values_list.insert(0, val2)

values_list = input().split(',')
swap(values_list)

print(values_list)
```

With an input of, say, `a,b,c,d,e` I expect to get back ['e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'] but instead I get ['e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd'].  What am I doing that makes Python think I'm trying to cram 'a' into the second-to-last place?  0 should remain the first element and -1 should remain the last element, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add element in Python to the end of list using list.insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212447/how-to-add-element-in-python-to-the-end-of-list-using-list-insert)

Comment: `.insert()` inserts the value _before_ the given index.  So yes, second-to-last place is correct behavior.

Comment: As an aside, this is an unnecessarily inefficient way to do this, it is O(N) time/space, you can do it in constant time /space using `values[0], values[-1] = values[-1], values[0]`

Comment: Oh!  Interesting.  I thought my problem was being caused by the popping beforehand, like that altered the list length in some way.  Thanks for your help!

Thank you, juanpa.arrivillaga, that's actually a pretty simple way I probably ought to have started out with.  Why is it unnecessarily inefficient, though?

Comment: You've received several good answers, but I will point out that what you tried to do with `values_list.insert(-1,val`) can actually be done as `values_list.append(val)`.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of
> the element **before** which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the
> front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to
> a.append(x).

So l.insert(-1, elem) inserts element **before** last one. Use just

```
l.insert(len(l), elem) # or l.append(elem)
```

Comment: The before is correct, but the code is not correct, you must use len(values_list) as the index, or append.

Comment: Better to fix trivial errors in code than complain about them, so I did.

Comment: right, thank you!